# Передача Func как параметр c#

Tags: c#

У меня есть класс

```
public class Dialog
    {
        public Dialog() { }
        public Dialog(Func<Dialog> func)
        {
            this.func = func;
        }

        private Func<Dialog> func;

        public string connectionString;

        public string string1;

        public string string2
        {
            get => string2;
            set
            {
                func();
            }
        }

        public string string3;

        public bool bool1;
    }
```

Как мне создать объект этого класа где в качестве параметра передаеться этот код

```
bool1 = false;
string3 = "";
if (string2.IndexOfAny(new char[] { ')', '(', '>', '<', '"', '\'', '=', '!', '?' }) != -1)
{
     string3 = "Нельзя использовать эти символы:()<>\"\'=!?";
}
else if (string2.Contains("USUMODEL"))
{
     string3 = "Нельзя использовать USUMODEL";
}
else if (string2.Contains("_COPY"))
{
     string3 = "Нельзя использовать _COPY";
}             
else
{
    if (string2.Trim() != string.Empty)
    {
        bool1 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: что за bool1, string3, string2? Это поля класса? Тогда в текущем виде - никак

Comment: @Grundy да это поля класса

Comment: @Grundy Вы понимаете что я хочу сделать?

Comment: По коду не очень: с одной стороны это просто инициализация полей, с другой - метод должен возвращать `Dialog`, но не возвращает ничего, плюс используется внутри сеттера.

Comment: @Dialog Я хочу при создании объекта класса передавать в него код которые должен выполняться в сеттере. Возвращать `Dialog` мне не надо. Я его написал так void нельзя

Comment: Если ты не хочешь ничего возвращать - используй `Action`

Comment: Вообще подход не очень хороший, когда установку полей выносишь из класса наружу. По сути тебе надо просто заменить `Func`, на `Action` и все заработает, Так как в этом случае придется передавать `this` внутрь `func` и через него обращаться к полям

Comment: @Grundy Так https://pastebin.com/v9WuzRNw?

Comment: да, примерно так. Обрати внимание, что внутри `Action` ты можешь обращаться только к публичным полям

Comment: @Grundy Понял, спасибо.